# Reading all of today's events using CalendarContract - Android 4.0+

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-calendar

I'm trying to use Android's new calendar API to read all of today's calendar events. I'm have trouble finding the right selection on the database query to return all of the events. It seems that all recurring and all day events are left out of the selection. What selection args would permit me to obtain all of today's events from the calendar api?

Here is my current attempt:

```
    Cursor cur = null;
    String selection = "((" + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART
            + " >= ?) AND (" + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " <= ?))";
    Time t = new Time();
    t.setToNow();
    String dtStart = Long.toString(t.toMillis(false));
    t.set(59, 59, 23, t.monthDay, t.month, t.year);
    String dtEnd = Long.toString(t.toMillis(false));
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { dtStart, dtEnd };
    cur = c.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
            null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

I am unsure of how to broaden the selection or adding to it to get the recurring events and all day events. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet??? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: I have found the solution. I will post it momentarily

Comment: @MobileMon I've posted the answer. Cheers! :D

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844770/how-to-get-access-to-the-calendars-on-a-android-phone

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To get all events today, including recurring events, you need to use the Instances table, i.e.

```
Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI
            .buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, timeNow);
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, endOfToday);
Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
Cursor cursor = null;       
cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, columns, null, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

Note that you must append the time constraints to the events uri, you cannot sort any other way.

In order to include all day events as well, just expand the the search to 11:59PM the previous night and 12:00AM tonight.

Comment: what can I put on "columns"?

Answer (score 5):

Your conditions only give you the events that are strictly in today limits. You should check the ones that start before today and end after (multidays event).

For recurring events, I check them manually. I don't found another way.

I use something like:

```
String selection = "((" + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= ?) AND (" + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " >= ?)) OR (" + CalendarContract.Events.RRULE + " is not null )";

String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { dtEnd, dtStart};
```

Regards,

Comment: To include recurring events, one must query the [CalendarContracts.Instance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to add the CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY to your selection condition to filter for all ALL_DAY events.

Comment: I have yet to find recurring events as they are not show to be a part of the current days date. How are the recurring events stored?

Comment: @BananaNutTruffles the reoccuring events are also mirrored in the Instances table. That is in contrast to the Events table that only contains the initial event that defines the sequence of "instances".

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but I had a very similar question and had trouble finding the answer I was looking for. The forced-UTC time zone for all-day events made things tricky. Here's my solution:

```
    // "allDayStart" is an all-day event today, encoded in the default time zone
    Time allDayStart = new Time();
    allDayStart.timezone=TimeZone.getDefault().toString();
    allDayStart.set(dayStart.monthDay, dayStart.month, dayStart.year);

    // 2 time selections for the query: 
        // 1) Between day-start and day-end (not all-day); or
        // 2) Equals today at 0:00:00 (all-day) in the default timezone
    String calSelection = 
        "((" + Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) " +
            "AND (" + Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + "= ?) " +
            "AND (" +
                "((" + Events.DTSTART + ">= ?) " +
                "AND (" + Events.DTSTART + "<= ?) " +
                "AND (" + Events.ALL_DAY + "= ?) " +
                ") " +
            "OR ((" + Events.DTSTART + "= ?) " +
                "AND (" + Events.ALL_DAY + "= ?)" +
                ")" +
            ")" +
        ")"; 

    String[] calSelectionArgs = new String[] {
        accountName, ownerName, 
        dayStartInMillis.toString(), dayEndInMillis.toString(), "0", // during today, not all day
        allDayStartInMillis.toString(), "1" // Started today at default start-time for all-day events (all-day), default time zone
    };
```

The query could be refined to not need 2 parts, but this was good enough for me.

In case it helps, here's where dayStart and dayEnd came from:

```
    Time dayStart = new Time();
    dayStart.setToNow();
    dayStart.hour=0;
    dayStart.minute=0;
    dayStart.second=0;

    Time dayEnd = new Time();
    dayEnd.set(dayStart);
    dayEnd.hour=dayStart.hour+23;
    dayEnd.minute=dayStart.minute+59;
    dayEnd.second=dayStart.second+59;

    Long dayStartInMillis = dayStart.toMillis(false);
    Long dayEndInMillis = dayEnd.toMillis(false) + 999;
    Long allDayStartInMillis = allDayStart.toMillis(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Instances.CONTENT_BY_DAY_URI. Check this answer for an example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622111/1219241