# get calendar event instance

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I want to get all of today's event instances. For that, I'm using the following code:

```
Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, start);
    ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, end);
 final Cursor cursorInstances = contentResolver.query(eventsUri, null, null, null, sortOrder);
```

It's fine except for all day event instances, it returns for both today and tomorrow!

**Update**
I know why is that because time zone of event instances with all day flag is Utc but I'm getting the event in local time so that's why but I still don't know how can I handle that.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code in this [SO post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13079522/8342742).

```
Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, timeNow);
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, endOfToday);
Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
Cursor cursor = null;       
cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(eventsUri, columns, null, null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

> **Note:** *You must append the time constraints to the events uri, you cannot sort any other way. In order to include all day events as well,
>   just expand the search to 11:59PM the previous night and 12:00AM
>   tonight.*